# Owl Carousel not created properly through AJAX/PHP call

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, owl-carousel

I am trying to convert the Owl Carousel to hold data pulled from a database. Using a button:

```
<button onclick="addCarousel('2015-06-11')">Test</button>
```

I call an AJAX function (the date is irrelevant for now):

```
function addCarousel(date){
  date = new Date(date);
  $.post("php/addCarousel.php", {date : date}, function(data){
    $('#ajaxResponse').html(data);
  });   
}:
```

which pulls data using PHP (static script for now):

```
Echo
'<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="scrollDay"><h1>0</h1></div>
    <div class="scrollDay"><h1>1</h1></div>
    <div class="scrollDay"><h1>2</h1></div>
    <div class="scrollDay"><h1>3</h1></div>
    <div class="scrollDay"><h1>4</h1></div>
    <div class="scrollDay"><h1>5</h1></div>
    <div class="scrollDay"><h1>6</h1></div>
    <div class="scrollDay"><h1>7</h1></div>
    <div class="scrollDay"><h1>8</h1></div>
    <div class="scrollDay"><h1>9</h1></div>
    <div class="scrollDay"><h1>10</h1></div>
    <div class="scrollDay"><h1>11</h1></div>
    <div class="scrollDay"><h1>12</h1></div>
    <div class="scrollDay"><h1>13</h1></div>
    <div class="scrollDay"><h1>14</h1></div>
    <div class="scrollDay"><h1>15</h1></div>
</div>';
```

Which populates on my index page

```
<div id="ajaxResponse">
   Data will go here
</div>
```

If I insert the elements into the index page directly then the carousel works fine, but it does not work when I generate it through php. My developer tools show that these elements exist on the page and there are no console errors, but the elements do not shown for some reason. I manually `display: block;` for all elements, but that's not the issue.

I think that I need to re-instantiate the code, but I'm not sure how and where to do that. I've looked into these articles [How to reinitialize Owl Carousel after ajax call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27802064/how-to-reinitialize-owl-carousel-after-ajax-call), [Owl carousel not displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25334574/owl-carousel-not-displayed), and [Call the plugin](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/#how-to). I've tried to instantiate in a number of way, but this is a bit foreign to me.

The instantiation below works fine when the elements are added directly to the index page

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var owl = $("#owl-demo"),
      status = $("#owlStatus");

  owl.owlCarousel({
    navigation : true,
    afterAction : afterAction
  });

  function updateResult(pos,value){
    status.find(pos).find(".result").text(value);
  }

  function afterAction(){
    updateResult(".owlItems", this.owl.owlItems.length);
    updateResult(".currentItem", this.owl.currentItem);
    updateResult(".prevItem", this.prevItem);
    updateResult(".visibleItems", this.owl.visibleItems);
    updateResult(".dragDirection", this.owl.dragDirection);
  }
});
```

**How and where do I re-instantiate after the PHP runs?**

Comment: do it in ajax call after this line  $('#ajaxResponse').html(data);

Comment: @user4621032 As per the documentation I should add $("#owl-example").owlCarousel();, but what element am I using? I tried $("#ajaxResponse") but that wasn't it

Comment: These data  id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel"

Comment: @user4621032 Excellent! It's not there 100% but a lot of the functionality is there now. Would you Post an answer so I can credit you? I'll edit with the complete answer once I've work it all out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should restart carousel (re-instantiate) in Ajax call. After then, when new elements are added to the page

```
function addCarousel(date){
  date = new Date(date);
  $.post("php/addCarousel.php", {date : date}, function(data){
    $('#ajaxResponse').html(data);
    $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel();
  });   
}
```